# Вывести список всех пользователей на сайте Modx Revo

Tags: modx, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите как показать на странице сайта всех пользователей по шаблону. 
Есть сниппет, который выводит конкретного пользователя:

```
$profile = $modx->user->getOne('Profile', 3);
$print_r($profile);
$fields = $profile->get('extended');
$ava =  $fields['avatar'];
$hob = $fields['hobby'];
$name = $profile->get('fullname');
$rodz = $fields['rodz'];
echo '<div id="zt-col1" class="zt-user zt-box-left" style="width: 32%;"><div class="zt-box-inside"><div class="moduletable"><div class="modulecontent"><div class="jv_news_wrap"><div class="jv-frame-cat"><div class="jv-category"><div class="jvpadding"><div class="cls"></div><ul class="lead"><li class="jv-article-title"><div class="img-round">
<a><div class="crop2"><img src="assets/avatar/'.$ava[name].'" width="200px"></div></a></div><h4>1.<a>'.$name.', '.$rodz.'</a></h4><p class="jv-sectcont-introtext"><b>Мои хобби:</b> '.$hob.'</p></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
```

как этот код переделать по вывод всех юзеров, например используя цикл while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уже нет необходимости в изобретении велосипеда нашел модуль Peoples, созданный как раз для таких нужд, но все равно спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

ну я так понимаю -

```
$profile = $modx->user->getOne('Profile', 3);
```

здесь переменная 3 задает id юзера.
ТОгда вам лучше вот весь этот код записать в функцию. Далее вам нада получить всех узеров , пройтись по ним циклом и в каждом цикле вызвать этот код (функцию).
Но я бы так не стал делать - слишком много запросов к базе.

Лучше сделать по другому -

1. Строим запрос на получение всех юзеров и выбираем только используемые далее поля (avatar, hobby, fullname, rodz)
2. Выполняем запрос.
3. ЧИтаем данные запроса до их окончания и с каждой записью результата(БД) производим вывод шаблона.